# HTML Table to Excel Javascript (tableToExcel is not defined )

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Whene im using this code from localhost this working ... but whene i insert into my server (winscp) and run again tell me 'tableToExcel is not defined'???

Export to Excel
.
.

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
    })()
```

Comment: For the love of god please format that code..

Comment: @RUJordan Formatted! You're welcome. :D

Comment: sorry its the first question for me .... can u help me plz... i dont now why its not working in winscp , whene in localhost its work perfectly